# Convergence of scrambled product for Dirichlet-$L$ function with modulo 4 character

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, riemann-zeta-function, dirichlet-series, euler-product

A Dirichlet-$L$ function is typically defined by its series, and its Euler product is a consequence of the definition. Here my approach is the other way around.

I define the function

$$ 
L_4^*(s) = \prod_{p\in P} \Bigg(1 - \frac{\chi(p)}{p^{s}}\Bigg)^{-1} 
$$
with $P=\{p_1,p_2,\dots\}$ the set of prime numbers but ordered differently so that the sequence $\chi(p_1),\chi(p_2),\dots$ is perfectly alternating. So
if $p_{k} \equiv 1 \bmod{4}$ then $p_{k+1}\equiv -1 \bmod{4}$. In this case, $p_{k+1}$ would be the smallest prime $> p_k$, equal to $-1$ modulo $4$, and not already used previously in the product.

Let's pretend that $L_4^*(s)$ is different from the standard function $L_4$ with the primes ordered by value in their natural order. After all no one knows, but  there is considerable empirical evidence that they are identical. Is $L_4^*$ analytical? Even if different from $L_4$, is it any easier to prove that the $L_4^*$ product converges if $\Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$?

In the end, does the above product define a nice $L$-function worth studying? To put it differently, would proving convergence for $L_4^*$ be a major milestone, or a useless result because $L_4^*$ does not belong to the category of "interesting functions" under GRH. The reason I am asking is because I am interested in finding a Dirichlet-$L$ function easier to study (the convergence) than the classic ones, yet featuring nice properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The usual Euler product converges absolutely in $\{s:\Re s>1\}$, hence no matter how you permute its factors, you get the same function in $\{s:\Re s>1\}$. This function has a unique analytic continuation to $\mathbb{C}$, which is then $L(s,\chi)$. In short, the new function you are trying to define will either not be analytic in $\mathbb{C}$, or it will not be new.

Comment: What would be the corresponding Dirichlet series for this "new" function (most likely not a new function, but we don't know)? If $\Re s>1$ of course it's the same Dirichlet series as $L(s, \chi_4)$.  But what if $0< \Re s < 1$? Do you mean it would not have a Dirichlet series? Because if it does, it would be analytic unless I am mistaken, no matter what that unknown Dirichlet series would be as long as it converges. And I remember a discussion (possibly from you) saying that if there is both a Dirichlet series and a product they must be identical even if convergence is not absolute.

Comment: [Continued] But I don't remember the exact details.   
I still have a major issue: the product $L_4^*$ has no visible root, yet when you compute it there are infinitely many zeros at $\Re s = \frac{1}{2}$. And of course $L_4^*$ (the product) must converge if $\Re s >0$ because it converges if $s$ is real because of the nature of the product (alternating, with the $p_k$ that tend to zero).

Comment: @VincentGranville: I am not sure you followed my answer. There is exactly one analytic function on $\mathbb{C}$ that agrees with $L_4^*(s)$ on $\{s:\Re s>1\}$, namely $L(s,\chi)$. In particular, in any half-plane where $L_4^*(s)$ converges, $L_4^*(s)$ agrees with $L(s,\chi)$. This is basic complex analysis.

Comment: It does agree based on empirical evidence. In short it offers to $L(s,\chi)$ a converging product on $\Re s > 0$ while the unscrambled, standard product is not known if it converges or not if $\Re s< 1$. Though everyone believe it does.

Comment: why do you claim that the product of $L_4^*$ converges even for real $s<1$; its logarithm has a term $\sum 1/p^{2s}$ which doesn't converge for $s \le 1/2$

Comment: And even for $1/2 < c \le 1$ why do you claim convergence of your modified product at $c$? This essentially means convergence of the alternating sum true, but note that by scrambling, the alternating terms are not decreasing anymore (eg now you have $3,5,7,13,11,17,19, 29, 23, 37, 31$ etc; the alternating convergence for series with terms going to zero works if the terms decrease monotonically otherwise taking $1/n$ for odd and $1/(3n)$ for even say you still get divergence as a simple counterxample

Comment: I will include my code that computes the standard product, the scrambled product, the Dirichlet series for $L(s,\chi_4)$, and the DirichletL function in Python from the MPmath library (I have no idea how it gets computed). When $\Re s > \frac{1}{2}$ the four methods yield the  same results in all my examples; in addition, it's the same as the result retuned by Mathematica. Not true when $\Re s < \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: That is not that surprising - for computable values of $s$ (and character of small enough modulus) the generalized RH has not been falsified so there is no low abscissa zero for $L_4$ not on the critical line; one can prove that the product converges whenever the corresponding $L_4$ series (which is the linear term in the logarithm of the product) converges to a non zero value and $\Re s >1/2$ so the square term in the logarithmic series is absolutely convergent; but there are good reasons to believe that the true behavior of $L_4$ is seen only at huge $\Im s$ far away from computable ones

Comment: True, the difficulties (and very slow convergence) is when $t=\Re s$ is large. Even $t=10^4$ shows challenges. But if the product converges when $t=0.4$, shouldn't it convergence for larger $t$? A possibility is that it converges but not to $L_4$ but instead to a value very close, with approximation error equal to $10^{-8}$. I need to use many millions of primes to get a good approximation.